# Azure Mobile Services Custom Authentication

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.forms

I am looking at adding custom authentication to my existing Xamarin.Forms app through Azure Mobile Services. Currently, my app authenticates itself against an existing WebAPI but the authentication isn't secure and I don't really want to start trying to create my own secure authentication process for production. I thought that Azure Mobile Services would be a good way of being able to keep the custom authentication side of my app (authentication against a current identity provider isn't an option) however I already have all the storage etc set up in an existing SQL database by sending it to the WebAPI first and then saving details.

I guess my question is: Is it possible to set up Azure Mobile Services with my current WebAPI acting as a kind of middleman? The basic workflow would include my app sending the log in details to the WebAPI, the WebAPI passing these on to Azure Mobile Services for authentication and then returning the response including token to the app after being stored on the WebAPI side.

The reason I thought that Azure Mobile Services would be a good choice was because it also provides support for push notifications as well as the custom authentication side of things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following for custom authentication: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/

Short version - yes, it is possible.  You create a custom WebAPI that mints a ZUMO token within your Azure Mobile Apps SDK  Within that minting process, you can check the users credentials (either a token, remote API or whatever) any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is possible. You are trying authenticate through two different application. It might be possible to write the mobile service client login code in your web API app to use authentication from Mobile Service app and get the token back. But then you still have to manage the user sessions between your Xamarin app and web api app, cross origin stuff and etc,

Since mobile service app really is a web api wrapped with some extra functionality, have you considered moving your web api app to mobile service? That might be easier in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
In our app the user is able to register and to login with twitter and Facebook but with own email + pw, too.
In wams we sync the social account and "our" account (stored in the db).

Have a look at [ClaimsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=DE-DE&k=k(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security IServiceTokenHandler to implement custom authentication and returning a custom token.